# Power BI Gateway Data Sources Usage and Statistics

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-gateway

I am trying to clean up my Power BI Data Gateway Data Sources.  How can I find data on which published reports use which data sources, and statistics on refresh times and failures?

Answer (score 0):

as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-modern-usage-metrics):

##### Prerequisites

1. You need a **Power BI Pro or Premium Per User (PPU) license** to access and run the metrics reports. *However*, the usage metrics feature **captures usage information from all users.**
2. To access these metrics the report **must** be in a modern workspace and you **must** have edit access to that report.
3. Your Power BI admin **must** have enabled usage metrics for content creators.
4. Only users with admin, member, or contributor permissions can view the improved usage metrics report.

##### Create the report

1. Open the workspace that contains the report for which you want to analyze the usage metrics.
2. Open the context menu of the report and select View usage metrics report.
   -- The first time you do this, Power BI creates the usage metrics report and lets you know when it's ready.

##### Reported Metrices

| Page | Metric | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Report usage | Report views/Report opens | A Report View is recorded each time someone opens a report and represents unique landings on the report. It answers the question, "How often is the report accessed?" This definition of a Report View differs from previous usage metrics reports. Changing report pages is no longer considered an additional Report View. Instead, changing report pages counts for the next metric, Report Page Views. Activities such as sharing and pinning are no longer considered in usage metrics. |
| Report usage | Report Page views | A Report Page View is recorded every time someone views a report page. It represents total views across any pages. It answers the question, "How often are report pages accessed?" So changing report pages counts for Report Page Views. See Considerations and Limitations for important details. |
| Report usage | Unique viewers | A viewer is someone who opened the report at least once during the time period (based on the AAD user account). |
| Report usage | View trend | The view trend reflects view count changes over time. It compares the first half of the selected time period with the second half. |
| Report usage | Date slicer | You can change the time period on the Report usage page, such as to calculate week-over-week or biweekly trends. In the lower left corner of the Report usage page, you can determine the earliest and latest date for which usage data is available for the selected report. |
| Report usage | Rank | Based on view count, the rank shows the popularity of a report in comparison to all other reports in the organization. A rank of 1 would mean the report has the most views of all reports in the organization. |
| Report usage | Report views per day | Total number of Report Views per day. Counted at report level, does not consider Report Page Views. |
| Report usage | Report viewers per day | Total number of different users who viewed the report (based on the AAD user account). |
| Report usage | Distribution method | How users got access to the report, such as being members of a workspace, having the report shared with them, or installing an app. |
| Report usage | Platform slicer | If the report was accessed via the Power BI service (powerbi.com), Power BI Embedded, or a mobile device. |
| Report usage | Users with report views | Shows the list of users who opened the report sorted by view count. |
| Report usage | Pages | If the report has more than 1 page, slice the report by the page(s) that was viewed. "Blank" means either a report page was added within 24 hours of the new page appearing in the slicer list, or report pages have been deleted. "Blank" captures these types of situations. |
| Report performance | Typical opening time | The typical report opening time corresponds to the 50th percentile of the time it takes to open the report. In other words, it is the time below which 50% of the open-report actions are completed. The Report performance page also breaks down the typical report opening time by consumption method and browser type. At present, we measure the performance for the initial report load and first page viewed. The measurement starts when the report is requested and ends when the last visual completes rendering. Report interactions such as slicing, filtering, or changing pages are not included in performance metrics. |
| Report performance | Opening time trend | The opening time trend reflects open-report performance changes over time. It compares the opening times for the report of the first half of the selected time period with the opening times of the second half. |
| Report performance | Date slicer | You can change the time period on the Report performance page, such as to calculate week-over-week or biweekly trends. In the lower left corner of the Report performance page, you can determine the earliest and latest date for which usage data is available for the selected report. |
| Report performance | Daily performance | The performance for 25%, 50%, and 75% of the open report actions calculated for each individual day. |
| Report performance | seven-day performance | The performance for 25%, 50%, and 75% of the open report actions calculated across the past seven days for each date. |
| Report performance | Consumption method | How users opened the report, such as via the Power BI service (powerbi.com), Power BI Embedded, or a mobile device. |
| Report performance | Browsers | What browser the users used to open the report, such as Firefox, Edge, and Chrome. |

Comment: Thanks @Guy for your quick response.  This is great for any particular report, but what I want is information by data source in the gateway.  I'd like to know which reports in the enterprise use each data source in the gateway.  Perhaps this is something I can get on the gateway server?